# Can anybody help me with math expressions?

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

So , I am in $7^{th}$ grade and my teacher gave me some really hard homework. What I have to do is use math expressions that equals each number between $1$ and $100$ , only using the numbers $1,2,3,4$. I really need help on this. Can anybody help?

Comment: The point of the problem is for you to play around and get as many as you can.

Comment: What's wrong with something like these?  $1=1$, $2 = 1+1$, $3 = 1+1+1, \ldots, 100 = \underbrace{1 + 1 + \cdots + 1 + 1}_{100 \text{ of them}}$

Comment: For this type of problem you are usually allowed to concatenate, and also use powers.  That will help you get some of the larger ones.  For example, $4^3+2+1=67$, $42+31=73$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking but I can take a gander:

Suppose you want to express, say, $63$ using only the numbers $1,2,3$, and $4$. We know that $63=60+3$, so all we have to do is express $60$. We also know that $60=3\times 20$, and $20$ is just $4+4+4+4+4$. We can write

$$63=3\times(4+4+4+4+4)+3$$

There will be many ways to write any given number. As another commenter noted, you can simply write $1+1+1+\cdots+1$, with $63$ ones (but that's not very interesting).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks That did help Elliot G

Comment: well it made it a little bit easier for me to do that math. I am not good at math at all. Lol

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to use each number more than once?  That makes it easy and also tedious, a poor homework problem.

Comment: I think so if this soundss confusing i am sorry but what i will do with that problem is divide it into sections. i know it might sound confusing.

Comment: I would have thought you wanted things like $2 = 4 + 2 - 1 - 3, 4 = 2^3 - 4^1, 5 = \dfrac{4}{2} + 3 \times 1, 10 = 4 \times 3 - 2 \times 1$.

Comment: I have no idea; like I said, the assignment here isn't totally clear. I sort of assumed the simplest interpretation since this is seventh grade math.

Comment: @SamBronson: Other examples include $27 = 23 + (4/1), 34 =  34 / 1^2, 38 =  42 - 3 - 1, 42 =  42 \times 1^3, 43 =  42 + 1^3, 44 =  43 + 1^2, 47 = 41 + 2 \times 3$